# How do I get a DateTimeTz column in the future?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a simple scope for a model which has "end_time" as a `dateTimeTz()` column in Laravel 5.8. I'm using:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereNull('end_time')->orWhere('end_time', '>', Carbon::now());
}
```

But this is only comparing the date element of the end_time column, and giving me everything ending strictly after today, when I want anything ending later on today as well.

What is the correct way of going about this?

Comment: Pls show more data example that  you expect

Comment: Nothing seems off in your query. What is the `end_time` column schema?

Comment: Also if your database server is MySQL, datetime is stored as UTC and you'll need to work around that.

Comment: It might be causing due to time UTC + timezone. So you must need to verify current time with Carbon::now() and then check if there is any matching records in database.